# Is it possible to infer a Dictionary(Of String, String) from its values (VB.Net)?

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

Apologies if the question isn't worded correctly in terms of terminology.  This type of thing is fairly new to me.

I am trying to convert the following ASP.Net C# code to VB.Net:

```
context.Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
{
    Dictionary = {
        { "foo", "bar" }
    }
}, new ClaimsIdentity());
```

The [Telerik code converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) throws this VB.Net back, but it doesn't compile:

```
context.Authentication.SignIn(New AuthenticationProperties() With {
    .Dictionary = {{"foo", "bar"}}
}, New ClaimsIdentity())
```

> BC30526   Property 'Dictionary' is 'ReadOnly'

So I rewrote it, which does work:

```
context.Authentication.SignIn(
    New AuthenticationProperties(
        New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"foo", "bar"}}), 
        New ClaimsIdentity())
```

While I'm happy with that, for my own understanding I was wondering if VB.Net supports any way to initialize that dictionary without explicity declaring as `Dictionary(Of String, String)`?  Like a lazy inference, of sorts?

Something like...

```
context.Authentication.SignIn(
    New AuthenticationProperties(
        New() From {{"foo", "bar"}}), 
        New ClaimsIdentity())
```

Comment: What about using `GetType` and if you have a constructed class as well you can do it..